# File transfer between Ionic (Angular, Browser) and AWS EC2 (Ubuntu)

Tags: angular, ubuntu, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2, file-transfer

My project requires user to import files (.csv and .json) from local directory and sent it to AWS EC2 to for processing. Then, the system will execute some command line, create and return a file (.json) and a link (url) to the user.

1. How to set up for both ionic? using FTP or File Transfer provided by ionic?
2. How to execute commands after EC2 receiving files?
3. What does endpoint API URL mean referring to EC2?

I am referring the code from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQtCVf7iGc4) which is using **File Chooser, File Path and File Transfer** but implemeted for android

```
 uploadFile() {
    this.fileChooser.open().then((uri)=>{
      this.filePath.resolveNativePath(uri).then(
        (nativepath)=>{
          this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
          let options:FileUploadOptions={
            fileKey:'videofile',
            fileName:'video.mp4',
            chunkedMode:false,
            headers:{},
            mimeType:'video/mp4'
          }
          this.uploadText = "uploading....";
          this.fileTransfer.upload(nativepath, 'endpoint API URL', options).then((data)=>{
            alert("transfer done = "+JSON.stringify(data));
            this.uploadText = "";
          },(err)=>{
            this.uploadText = "";
          })
        },(err)=>{
          alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        })
    },(err)=>{
      alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
  }
```

For EC2, I am implementing SFTP from [this website](https://blog.e-zest.com/setting-up-sftp-server-on-amazon-ec2)

Thanks for helping~~

Comment: I have tried using the code below for selecting the file from local directory but i have no idea on how to send it to EC2.

Comment: home.page.ts
`fileChange(file) {
    this.file = file.target.files[0];
    this.file_name = this.file.name;
  }`

Comment: home.page.html
`<input type="file" accept=".csv" style="display: none" #file (change)="fileChange($event)"/>
          <ion-button (click)="file.click()">Browse</ion-button>`

Comment: frontend will never send file directly to OS, instead send to a web app or an endpoint (API). My resolution is hosting my python script using flask and access the python script via the domain name